# Restoring data from hard disk without formatting

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I'm trying to recover a hard disk with a capacity of 750 GB. All data from the "C:" drive needs to be recovered. Now here is the strange thing:

Partition 1: 350gb -> 350gb free space
Partition 2: 150mb -> 150mg free space
Partition 3: no result -> I can't see how many space is available or used. When I open that partition it asks me to format it.

I don't want to format the disk drive because I want to recover the data that is on the harddisk. What can I do?

Comment: What are the drive letters associated with the partition (please edit into the question)?

Comment: Whatever you try, if your data is really important, you should make a 1-to-1 copy of the entire disk before letting any software do its recovery work - unless you know that that software will not change logical structures on the disk.

Comment: First you might have to accept that you  might not be able to recover the data.  File recovery software of your choice is likely the best way to recover the data.  DO NOT WRITE ANY additional data to the hdd otherwise the lost data WILL BE LOST if not already lost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a partition recovery tool. When I've had a faulty partition table on a hard disk drive, I've used TestDisk. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step.

TestDisk will scan the first section of your hard disk and see if there is something that can be rebuilt - then give you the option to restore it. Sometimes it works, othertimes it doesn't.

If you cannot recover the partition tables, it's going to be very difficult to recover. You can use the accompanying tool - PhotoRec - to 'scrape' the disk and recover any files that it finds. It won't know the filenames and it will only find contiguous files.

I'm not sure how much and what kind of data you're trying to recover so these would be my starting points.

As with any recovery techniques - try and create a clone of the disk first so that you can go back to where you are now.

Comment: This should probably be done on a clone, not on the real drive.

Comment: Good point - I added that to the answer. At the very least, a copy of the partition table to ensure that it can be experimented on and restored quickly.